# iOS AVPlayer won't play

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I have the following code set up to play a video in my iOS app, but it just doesn't play. The app compiles and runs, but all I get a red frame where I positioned it. When debugging, I found that the the program doesn't even step into the last line [player play]. Also, the video runs fine in a UIWebView.

```
NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://youtu.be/...."];

AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streamingString]];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];

[layer setPlayer:player];

[layer setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 400, 300)];
[layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

[player play];
```

I am a new programmer and this is my first post to Stackoverflow, so please excuse me if I have not given enough information or am missing something obvious! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assetWithURL:` is often, but not always, used with a URL that points to a file already on the device, often within the bundle.  If you are using an external URL, such as one on the internet, the url must resolve to a video that is in a format that the `AVPlayer` can understand.  A URL to a YouTube web page will not work.  In general, you can't play a YouTube video in `AVPlayer`.

Check out this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3) from Apple and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGbuq_OJINU) on YouTube.

EDIT:

Some developers have used [this library](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) to play a YouTube video in their app.  Another option is to use a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I replaced my YouTube video URL with the test stream given in the Apple document and it worked. I don't actually need to play a YouTube video; I was just using it to test. Now I just need to figure out how to get the videos I do need into the format of the test stream.... but at least I'm onto the next step. Thanks again!